# Difference of mongoose transaction session on save and on find

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

Is there a difference between these two approach.

```
const something = Model.findById(id).
something.save({ session })
```

```
const something = Model.findById(id).session(({ session })
something.save()
```

When testing it, the functionality is the same. What should be right way to use session in mongoose transaction.

Comment: You're not changing anything in the document, so why are you saving it?

Answer (score 8):

first of all in transaction you need to `async/await`,

```
const something = await Model.findById(id).
await something.save({ session })
```

but transactions let you execute multiple operations in `isolation` and `potentially` undo all the operations if one of them fails and the primary goal of a transaction is to let you `update multiple documents` in MongoDB in isolation.

but in your example you update one collection, and don't need to transaction. let's move on... see the following exmaple, in this example result is diffrence, this `create()` is part of the transaction because of the `session` and transactions execute in isolation, so unless you pass a `session` to `findOne()` you won't see the result until the transaction is committed. so result of `findOne` is `Null`

```
const session = await db.startSession();
session.startTransaction();
await Model.create([{ name: 'Test' }], { session: session });
let result = await Model.findOne({ name: 'Test' });//without session
session.endSession();
```

in the following exapmle, this `findOne()` will return the result, because passing the `session` means this `findOne()` will run as part of the transaction.

```
const session = await db.startSession();
session.startTransaction();
await Model.create([{ name: 'Test' }], { session: session });
let result = await Model.findOne({ name: 'Test' }).session(session);
session.endSession();
```

If you get a Mongoose document from findOne() or find() using a session the document will keep a reference to the session and use that session for save(), in the following example
Won't find the `result` because `save()` is part of an uncommitted transaction, but `firstReuslt` is not `Null`

```
const session = await db.startSession();
session.startTransaction();
await Model.create({ name: 'Test' });
const something  = await Model.findOne({ name: 'Test' }).session(session);
something.name = 'firstTest';
await something.save();

let result = await Model.findOne({ name: 'firstTest' }); //Is Null
await session.commitTransaction();
session.endSession();

firstReuslt = await Model.findOne({ name: 'firstTest' });//Is Not Null
```

if you want update two collection like following code, should use `save({ session: sess })` but when you want update one collection you don't need because:

**if you get a Mongoose document from findOne() or find() using a session the document will keep a reference to the session and use that session for save()**:

```
const sess = await mongoose.startSession();
sess.startTransaction();
await first.save({ session: sess }); 
await second.save({ session: sess });
await sess.commitTransaction();
```

Comment: I understand last part of code explain putting session while finding this explain good. Can you explain if I put session in .save()?

Comment: I updated my answer, I hope your problem is solved

Comment: So basically I will put session on save() when updating two or more collections right? But when I put session while finding the object and no session in save. 

It has same function it also revert back if I aborted it.

Comment: if you want find just one document and save() it in a real project, you don't need to use session,just put `find` and `save` in `try/catch`, and when you want update  two or more collections use session

Comment: These examples are fine, but misses the point. You should **not** be using `findOne` and `save`, anyway. Use `updateOne` for atomic operations. Otherwise, a delete op could happen after the find, but before the save from some other client, then you are re-inserting what **should** have been deleted.